# Solver VBA, how to paste "SolverSolve return value" for every row

Tags: excel, vba, solver

I have created the following macro, which loops through a set of rows optimising product price for every row.

```
Sub OptimizePrice()
Dim i As Integer
ActiveWorkbook.ActiveSheet.Activate
For i = 5 To 20
SolverReset
SolverOk SetCell:="$K$" & i, MaxMinVal:=1, ByChange:="$B$" & i, Engine:=1
SolverAdd CellRef:="$B$" & i, Relation:=1, FormulaText:="$E$" & i
SolverAdd CellRef:="$F$" & i, Relation:=1, FormulaText:="$G$" & i
SolverSolve True
Range("$L$" & i)= SolverSolve Return Value
Next i
End Sub
```

Sometimes Solver finds an optimal solution, sometimes it doesn't. I want my macro to PASTE for every row in column "L", the result of the operation, which ranges from 0 to 20 according to the description provided in the following webpage: https://www.solver.com/excel-solver-solversolve-function.

I've tried to achieve this with this line of code 'Range("$L$" & i)= SolverSolve Return Value' but it seems it's not the right way to get the returnvalue type.

Your help is appreciated!.

Comment: Will this work? `Range("$L$" & i)= SolverSolve Return Value` -> `Cells(i, "L").Value = SolverSolve`

Comment: Thanks it worked, I just modified my code based on your suggestion: Cells(i, "L").Value = SolverSolve. However I don't see a button to accept your post as an answer! Not sure if I have to wait

Comment: I'm happy it worked :). Reason is that I didn't post it as a answer, but as a comment. I posted an answer (which can be accepted if you want to) and some small advice regarding the `ActiveWorkbook.ActiveSheet.Activate`. Happy coding :)!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change this line:

```
Range("$L$" & i)= SolverSolve Return Value
```

Into something like this:

```
ws.Cells(i, "L").Value = SolverSolve
```

---

I would also recommend to use the declared variable of worksheet (`ActiveWorkbook.ActiveSheet.Activate`)

Reason is, if we use the above line, we want to make sure the code runs on the "correct" worksheet.

```
Dim ws As Worksheet
Set ws = ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet1")
ws.activate 'Should be avoided but can be nice for now, since you might avoid to rewrite some code.
```